# find string and print first and last characters of line

Tags: sed, grep, cut

I have files with hundreds of lines of varying length. I want to find each line with the string "New" and print the first 7 characters and the 10th from the last character.

For example,  `cat file1.txt`

```
1234567 New line with irrelevant info x end line
2345678 irrelevant line
3456789 New line with different irrelevant info y end line
4567890 irrelevant line
5678901 New line with yet more irrelevant info z end line
```

And my output would be:

```
1234567 x 
3456789 y
5678901 z
```

Comment: Expected output seems wrong .... second line starting with `2345678` is irrelevant.

Comment: ... as is the third.

Answer (score 4):

POSIXly:

Assuming the lines contain at least 10 characters (if not, the behaviour is unspecified for the second `substr()`, you can add a `&& length >= 10` or `&& length >= 17` after `/New/` to skip the lines that have fewer than 10 or 17 characters):

```
awk '/New/ {print substr($0, 1, 7), substr($0, length - 9, 1)}'
```

or assuming the lines contain at least 17 characters (the lines that don't will be skipped):

```
sed -n '/New/ s/^\(.\{7\}\).*\(.\).\{9\}$/\1 \2/p'
```

Comment: What is the difference with the answer of RomanPerekhrest ? Your awk solution is identical and your sed solution is also identical, it just uses basic regex instead of extended regex....

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou, he edited the `awk` solution in after I had started writing mine and I hadn't seen his edit before I posted mine. His `sed` one is GNU specific, my intention was to offer a standard solution.

Comment: ok then. Fair answer. Has happened also to me. If i had more time my answer would also be like Roman's answer, but this guy was fast! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Choose one you like:

**`awk`** solution:

```
awk '/New/{ print substr($0, 1, 7), substr($0, length-9, 1) }' file1.txt
```

---

**`sed`** solution:

```
sed -rn '/New/ s/^(.{7}).*(.).{9}$/\1 \2/p' file1.txt
```

---

Sample output (for both approaches):

```
1234567 x
3456789 y
5678901 z
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one "brutal" `gawk` solution that does the job, using `null` as field separator `FS` and output field separator `OFS` , meaning each char of inputfile is considered to be a field for awk.

```
awk '/New/{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7," ",$(NF-9)}' FS="" OFS="" file1
1234567 x
3456789 y
5678901 z
```

More solutions with grep / sed will follow.

Answer (score -1):

For variety, a bash only solution. When processing mulitple lines in a file, sed and awk are usually better tools but bash will get the job done. The string slicing variable expansions here are handy.

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  # Check the line length.
  # This could be whatever test defines an irrelevant line.
  if [ "${#line}" -lt "25" ]
  then
    continue
  fi

  printf '%s\n' "${line:0:7} ${line: -10:1}"
done < file1.txt
```

Output

```
1234567 x
3456789 y
5678901 z
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas addressed your comments, other than shell looping to process a text file which is inherent to the solution. As I noted, sed and awk are better tools for the job but I think this solution is good for illustrating how variable expansion can address the problem.

Comment: I don't think it's appropiate to downvote an illustrative example because it is not your preferred solution.

Comment: I wasn't the one down voting, I'm pointing out how difficult it is to get that kind of approach right . Your answer is now much better than it was initially

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thank you for all the input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129476/discussion-between-tony-and-stephane-chazelas).

Comment: Regarding the efficiency of bash loops vs sed or awk, the OP said the files had hundreds of lines. Fine-tuning the efficiency really doesn't matter. It's really more important which tool someone can use more quickly to solve the problem rather than how quickly the solution runs.